# Split a vector into multiple vectors in R

Tags: r

I want to split one vector(x) into multiple vectors(x1, x2 ,... , xn).

My input: x <- 1:10

My desire output:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
x2 <- c(2,3,4,5)
x3 <- c(3,4,5,6)
x4 <- c(4,5,6,7)
x5 <- c(5,6,7,8)
x6 <- c(6,7,8,9)
x7 <- c(7,8,9,10)
```

My code(thanks to Mrs.Richard Herron for inspiration):

```
x <- 1:10
n <-3
vectors <- function(x, n) split(x, sort(rank(x) %% n))
vectors(x,n)
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: You could use data.table's `shift` function as in `lapply(shift(test, 0:6), tail, 4)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the sequence of 'x' such that we have a `length` of 4 in each of the elements in `list`, create a sequence (`:`) from that index to index + n, subset the 'x'.  If needed to have individual `vector`s, we set the names of the `list` and use `list2env`.

```
n <- 3
lst <- lapply(1:(length(x)-n), function(i) x[i:(i+n)])
names(lst) <- paste0("x", seq_along(lst))
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
x1
#[1] 1 2 3 4
x2
#[1] 2 3 4 5
x3
#[1] 3 4 5 6
```

---

Or we can also create a `matrix` instead of multiple `vector`s in the global environment where each row corresponds to the vector of interest

```
matrix(x[1:4] + rep(0:6, each = 4), ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yeah ! Good job !     Thanks very much !